# Are questions about specific web apps, i.e. ChatGPT, on-topic on AI?

Tags: support, scope

This question is inspired by the hype about ChatGPT and by a question that was migrated to Web Applications that recently was returned to this site:

[OpenAI ChatGPT gives network error at long responds. How to fix it?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/38268/42632) (closed)

Notes: Contrary as happens on Super User and other technology SE sites, troubleshooting like questions are off-topic in Web Applications.

Trying to understand why this question was migrated from this site / why is closed I have being exploring and found some questions including the word "ChatGPT".

Here I found [Please do not post AI-generated content as actual posts](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2905/42632).

On the main site besides the first linked question, one is closed but the others are apparently are well received

- [How do ChatGPT content filters work? (If not chatGPT then in general)](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/38315/42632)
- [Did anyone facing issues with chatGPT(openai)?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/38279/42632) (closed)

  - > I’m voting to close this question because it's a question about a website, no specifically about AI

    [Quote Source](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/38279/did-anyone-facing-issues-with-chatgptopenai#comment57196_38279)
- [How does an AI answer a question in a subject which it may not know?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/38270/42632)
- [Why is ChatGPT bad at math?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/38220/42632)
- [How does ChatGPT know math?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/38217/42632)
- [Why don't OpenAI train a deep learning model to identify correct and incorrect information in ChatGPT's responses?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/38196/42632)
- [How does ChatGPT retain the context of previous questions?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/38150/42632)

What kind of questions about web apps like ChatGPT might be well received on this site? In other words, how could be a good way to refer this site to people asking questions about ChatGPT and other similar web apps on other SE sites?

Answer (score 5):

Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange comes [from the "Science" category of Area 51](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1144/145). The site as a whole is designed for questions from a scientific, theoretical, social, historical, and ethical point of view; implementation and technical questions were not part of that.
As the scope has evolved over the years, we've allowed more questions about the technical aspects of different AI and ML systems, but general consensus, as far as I understand, has remained that debugging and technical support questions are off-topic.

The well-received questions about ChatGPT that you've linked are about the scientific background of the AI. Questions about how the backend works are coming from a scientific "how does this work". Questions about using the interface are coming from a technical "how do I use this". "how does this work" questions are generally on-topic; "how do I use this" are typically not.

---

I migrated the question to Web Applications after browsing your [on-topic page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I saw that "...any other website which behaves like an application" was on-topic, and troubleshooting / errors didn't appear in the list of off-topic subjects. I'd recommend updating that page if such questions are indeed off-topic.

The question has attracted about 50k views in its time being bounced across sites, so it's obviously a question that people are searching for. It's just unfortunate that there doesn't seem to be a SE site that it fits on.

Comment: When in doubt to which site to migrate, it might be good idea just to close the post, at least temporarily until one finds the right site to migrate to, and maybe by locking it to prevent more interactions (e.g. if it has historical significance). The most we can do is just comment that the question/problem is off-topic and tell the user that it might be on-topic somewhere else.